# Understanding Java instances and the STATIC keyword

Tags: java, static, instance, static-methods

what can I do to use the `getTotalScore` method on the Program class to get the total of my `scores ArrayList`, and why must I do that? I wanna understand. Please note I don't wanna make the method static.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {

    public int getTotalScore(ArrayList<int> v) {
        
        return total;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<int> scores = new ArrayList<>();


}
}
```

I can't find an article to help me understand clearly what is up, please help. I got this comment somewhere:

> Note that the scores object is not static, so you will have to make an instance of the
> `Program` class in order to use the scores `ArrayList` and the `getTotalScore` method.

Comment: `getTotalScore` is an instance method, which means you need an instance of the class to call the method on. So first create an instance: `Program p = new Program();`. Then call the method on that instance: `int r = p.getTotalScore(scores);`. Also, note that primitives cannot be used as generic type arguments. In other words, you can't use `ArrayList<int>`, it would instead be `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Fundamentally, understanding the difference beween classes and instances is basic to programming in Java.   It's not tricky, though.   Think of the difference between the class String and "a String" as it appears in your program.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a non-static member of a class, you must instantiate the class. So in this case

```
new Program().getTotalScore(scores)
```

This is very weird, to create an instance of the `Program` class. Move the method `getTotalScore` to a new class instead (or make it static).

For calculating the total, look up how to “sum” an array of integers.

Comment: Thanks, the code I wrote there was just so sum1 can explain using it so I can know what to do on the actual problem I'm solving, thank u so much nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

`static` members belong to a class, not an instance.

In order to use `getTotalScore` method inside your `main` method, you'll either have to create an object that is instance of `Program`, or make `getTotalScore` a static method.

Here are two examples:

1. Creating an instance of `Program`

```
public class Program {

    public int getTotalScore(ArrayList<Integer> v) {
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            total += v.get(i);
        }
        return total;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Program program = new Program();
        program.getTotalScore(scores);
    }
}
```

2. Making `getTotalScore` a static method

```
public class Program {

    public static int getTotalScore(ArrayList<Integer> v) {
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            total += v.get(i);
        }
        return total;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Program.getTotalScore(scores);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Q71700414 {
public int getTotalScore(ArrayList<Integer>  v) {
    int total=0;;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {
        total+=v.get(i);
    }
    return total;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer>v=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        v.add(i+1);
    Q71700414 obj=new Q71700414();
    System.out.println("Total is "+obj.getTotalScore(v));
    System.out.println("Total is "+new Q71700414().getTotalScore(v));
}
```

}

Here I have include two type of instatiate object(in this case calling method).